# Can I melt the plug fuse metal strip using heat?

Tags: heat, fuses

Since I do not have a lot of equipment right now, I am trying to find an alternative to strip a plug fuse using fire or heat. I tried to put it on heat for about 2 minutes, but when I tried it again, it is still working. Is this even possible?

Comment: Depends on how hot you got it.

Comment: Approximately, what would be the temperature to melt it? I believe I got it for about 80 degree Celsius.

Comment: I expect the melting point is well above 100 C, but I try not ot melt fuses, so don't know.

Comment: why are you doing this? ... it makes me think that your end goal is something different

Comment: What does "to strip a plug fuse" mean? What is a "plug fuse"?

Comment: @jsotola am trying to do this because of annoying housemate that doesn't know how to listen to lower down the volume. Anyway, I did an old school trick by shorting the fuse using a fork.

Comment: @Transistor [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.co.uk%2FAll-Trade-Direct-Household-Electrical%2Fdp%2FB00904SE5U&psig=AOvVaw3naS9488kZnlWtjSj8_Mbs&ust=1606550808901000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCIDB_qOiou0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)

Comment: You are not trying to "strip" a fuse. You are trying to "blow" it or make it go open-circuit. You didn't short the fuse - you shorted the supply. Using a fork sounds dangerous and well up on the stupidity scale. You could have just removed the fuse.

Comment: @Transistor if I removed it, it would be physically missing instead of melting the strip metal inside. Thanks for correcting the term. Well I am trying to do an alternative since I do not have all the great equipment in the first place. So that's why I came up using fork.

Comment: What kind of "plug fuse" is this? To me, it means the fuse in a BS1363 plug : one screw at most and you can pull the fuse out. No need to apply heat.

Comment: @Rich what is preventing your housemate from replacing the fuse?

Comment: @jsotola troubleshooting skills.

Comment: @Rich lol ... are you saying that your housemate is as dumb as bag of hammers?

Comment: @jsotola well, I didn't say that. Just implying it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need more than 80C. Need more info about the fuse and material of the fuse strip.

This link may help,
https://circuitglobe.com/fuse-wire-materials.html

Comment: Wow. It really wouldn't easy to melt it by heat then.

Comment: If a large amount of current went thorugh it (as it is slightly resistive, then it would be quite easy to melt.  But you know that, because that's what it is designed to do. :)

Comment: It may be easy to short circuit using 12V high discharge rate battery (Lead Acid Car battery or LiPo) without any over current protection circuit (direct connection short circuit through fuse) to blow your fuse and try to obtain the temperature from that way. But if your fuse amp rating is way higher than normal 5,15,20A fuse, you may need bigger power source.

Comment: Yep, you are right. It is easier to use electricity to melt this in nanosecond, I did the old school short circuiting it using fork and 220 voltage. No it isn't working anymore